# json template engine in node.js

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, templates

I have a json template like the following:

```
[
  {
    "type":"foo",
    "config":"{config}"
  },
  {
    "type":"bar",
    "arrConfig":"{arrConfig}"
  }
]
```

While i have a backing model like:

```
{
  "config": {
    "test1": "value1",
    "test2": "value2"
  },
  "arrConfig": [
    "test3": {
      "key1": "val1"
    },
    "test4": {
      "key1": "val1"
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm wondering if there are any node modules out there which will automatically take these two and transform the placeholders in the template. So the output would look like:

```
[
  {
    "type":"foo",
    "config":{
      "test1": "value1",
      "test2": "value2"
    }
  },
  {
    "type":"bar",
    "arrConfig": [
      "test3": {
        "key1": "val1"
      },
      "test4": {
        "key1": "val1"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: I mean a quick & dirty solution would to just do text replacement on the JSON. You could write your own function to recursively traverse an object hierarchy and replace matching text values.

Comment: I think it's a bit more complex that since the placeholder values might be an object, array, string, number etc... So accordingly i will have to replace it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a function to traverse an object hierarchy and replace template strings, as specified:

```js
// modifies the object passed, and returns the same object
function applyTemplate(template, backing) {
  for (var i in template) {
    var m = /^{(.+)}$/.exec(template[i]);
    if (m && backing[m[1]]) {
      // replace with a deep clone of the value from the backing model
      template[i] = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(backing[m[1]]));
    } else if (template[i] && "object" == typeof template[i]) {
      // traverse down recursively
      applyTemplate(template[i], backing);
    }
  }
  return template;
}

var template = [
  {
    "type":"foo",
    "config":"{config}"
  },
  {
    "type":"bar",
    "arrConfig":"{arrConfig}"
  }
];

var backing = {
  "config": {
    "test1": "value1",
    "test2": "value2"
  },
  "arrConfig": {
    "test3": {
      "key1": "val1"
    },
    "test4": {
      "key1": "val1"
    }
  }
};

applyTemplate(template, backing);
console.log(JSON.stringify(template, null, 2));
```

Plus a proof-of-concept using raw JSON text replacement (**not robust, don't actually use this**; but works for the vast majority of scenarios):

```
function applyTemplateStr(template, backing) {
  template = JSON.stringify(template);
  for (var key in backing) {
    template = template.split('"{'+key+'}"').join(JSON.stringify(backing[key]));
  }
  return JSON.parse(template);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

`JSON.stringify` accepts a replacer param that you could use to do it.

This should work:

```
var template = [
  {
    "type":"foo",
    "config":"{config}"
  },
  {
    "type":"bar",
    "arrConfig":"{arrConfig}"
  }
];


var data = {
  "config": {
    "test1": "value1",
    "test2": "value2"
  },
  "arrConfig": {
    "test3": {
      "key1": "val1"
    },
    "test4": {
      "key1": "val1"
    }
  }
};

var replacer = function (key, val) {
   if (typeof val === 'string' && val.match(/^{(.+)}$/)) {
     return data[val.replace(/[{|}]/g, '')]
   }
   return val;
 }

 console.log(JSON.stringify(template, replacer));
```

And if you want to transform it back to an object you can use `JSON.parse`

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Mustache](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mustache), like so:

```
var template = [
  {
    type: "foo",
    config: "{{config}}"
  }
];

var data = {
  config: "hello"
};

const Mustache = require("mustache");

function render(template, data) {
  return Mustache.render(JSON.stringify(template), data);
}

var output = render(template, data);
console.log(output);  // [{"type":"foo","config":"hello"}]
```